# Calculate Conversion "Weight" based on Multiple Conversions

Tags: optimization, statistics, probability, data-conversion, bayesian

I'd like to estimate the value of each "conversion" starting from a free trial signup all the way to that user becoming a paid user.

Let's say I have an online coding course website that offers a free 30-day trial. After the trial period, the cost is $100 per month.

- I bring in **100,000** users/mo to the signup page of my site via Google Ads paid search
- I consistently get ~**1,000** free trial signups per month (1% conversion rate). All signups are considered free trial users

---

- Of the 1,000 trial users, **500** log in exactly **2x** within the first week (let's call these **L2W1** for Logged in 2x within Week 1)
- Of the 1,000 trial users, **100** log in at least **3x** within the first week (**L3W1**). These users are mutually exclusive from above

---

- Of the **500 L2W1** users, **50 users** (10%) sign up for at least 1 course
- Of the **100 L3W1** users,  **50 users** (or 50%) sign up for at least 1 course

---

- On average, I get **35** paid users monthly

  - **10** of 50 L2W1 users become Paid Users
  - **25** / 50 L3W1 - in other words, 50% of L3W1 Users convert to a Paid User

---

To recap, assume these are the only events that I am currently tracking:

- 100,000 Site Visitors ---> 1,000 Trial Signups
- 500 L2W1 ---> 50 Course Signups (CS) ---> 15 Paid Users = $1,000
- 100 L3W1 ---> 50 Course Signups (CS) ---> 35 Paid Users = $2,500
- Total: 35 Paid Users (PU) ---> **$3,500**

To keep things simple, let's ignore life-time value (e.g. the average user subscribes for 3.5 months).

**QUESTION**: Is there a mathematical equation I could use to assign values (or percentages) to each conversion event? As I receive more information, I'd like to provide that to Google as a signal that each conversion type down the funnel is a sign of a more qualified user and therefore more valuable to my business.

I can simply take the 1,000 Trial Signups and divide $3,500 (and ignore all other conversion types) in which case each Trial Signup is worth $3.50. However, only 35/1000 Trial Users convert to a Paid User so there is valuable information I am leaving on the table and not informing Google for automated bidding purposes.

I'm thinking something like this is better:

- 1 Trial Signup = $1.00
- 1 L2W1 = $2.00
- 1 L3W1 = $3.00
- 1 CS = $4.00
- 1 PU = $90.00

.. so a Paid User who goes through several of the steps above will equate to about $100. Not sure if this is a good approach or if the math makes sense. Any pointers or tips would be greatly appreciated.

I've been reading on Bayes Theorem and it seems to be a good model to use for this case but I'm not at all familiar with it enough to know if it's applicable to this situation.

Comment: I think you're doing a great job of thinking it through. You could formalize this to some extent in terms of conditional probabilities -- this is where Bayes' theorem comes into the picture -- but to be honest it's not clear to me how much of an improvement it would be. For the record, a question like this is off topic in this forum; try stats.stackexchange.com for further discussion. Also, since you are working with actual dollar values, you will want to look at utility theory and decision theory (Bayes' theorem comes into that as well). Good luck and keep up the good work.

Comment: thanks for such a kind response, Robert! I will heed your advice RE the stats forum, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!